# Cross-Domain tracking between website and app

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I got a website ( with a ga property and a gtm container) and an app (single page react, android/ios with firebase.sdk, a ga property and a gtm container).

From the website you can get to the app (shop) and my task is to cross-domain track these two.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to accomplish that the best way?
The website will be the same tech-stack as the app (in the future), should i wait for that to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **Google Analytics 4** properties and relative tags.

Google Analytics 4 (GA4) properties enable unified measurement of user interactions and events between your website and app.

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/9442095?hl=en

Comment: The Beta-State of those Tags is not really attractive to me. Is there no other way?

Comment: Consider that before being called GA4 it was called App + Web, that was the beta.